# how to style table row using XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have this working xslt but have the issue to show alternative color on table rows. the row color is coming but not alternative row's because of the recursive its getting effected after parent tag is completed

can you please help me

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
   <html>
   <body>
   <table border="1">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
   </table>
   </body>
   </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[text()]">

  <xsl:variable name="altColor">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 0">#FFFFFF</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>#D3DFEE</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
  
  <tr bgcolor="{$altColor}">
    <td>
    <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>_</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </td>
    <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </td>
  </tr>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

input sample xml is this

```html
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xmltohtmlrecurnewfromAns.xsl"?>
<A>
   <B>Text</B>
   <C>Text</C>
   <D>
      <D1>Text</D1>
      <D2>
          <D3>Text</D3>
          <D4>Text</D4>
      </D2>
   </D>
   <E>
      <E1>
          <E2>
              <E3>Text</E3>
          </E2> 
      </E1>
   </E>
</A>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing it recursively by using `<xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>`, you can simply select all the "leaf" elements in one select.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//*[text()]"/>
```

This way your logic to check the position will then work as expected.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
   <html>
   <body>
   <table border="1">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="//*[text()]"/>
   </table>
   </body>
   </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:variable name="altColor">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 0">#FFFFFF</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>#D3DFEE</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>

  <tr bgcolor="{$altColor}">
    <td>
    <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>_</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </td>
    <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </td>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```